Disabling write protection on Windows
I've been learning win internals and I came across an interesting thing called Write Protection.
I know Windows relies on interrupts but I don't know any other way to do this.
I decided to try it using
__writecr0(__readcr0 & ~0x10000);

Unfortunately that didn't work for me so I decided to do it directly in the memory
I allocated memory, put opcodes there so it represents
cli
mov eax, cr0
and eax, not 0x10000
mov cr0, eax
sti

This didn't work either, I even wrote a code for it.
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS NTAPI
DriverEntry(
    PDRIVER_OBJECT          DriverObject,
    PUNICODE_STRING         RegistryPath
) {
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(DriverObject);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(RegistryPath);

    unsigned char Opcodes[] =
        { 0x48, 0x0F, 0x20, 0xC0, 0x48, 0x0D, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x48, 0x0F, 0x22, 0xC0, 0xC3 };

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "cr0: %I64X", __readcr0()));

    VOID* Memory = ExAllocatePool2(
        POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED, 1024, 1337
    );
    if (Memory == NULL)
        return STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

    RtlCopyMemory(Memory, Opcodes, sizeof(Opcodes));

    ((VOID (*) ())Memory)();

    KdPrintEx((DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_ERROR_LEVEL, "cr0: %I64X", __readcr0()));

    ExFreePoolWithTag(Memory, 1337);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

Still nothing, don't mind the different opcodes I tried without the REX (48h)
But I noticed that whenever I set the EIP to the address of these instructions I get a BSOD instantly when it comes to "cli"
Why do I get a BSOD when I try to disable interrupts and how else can I disable write protection if not like this?
/ EDIT /
I noticed this
*** Fatal System Error: 0x00000050
(0xFFFFC88F150D88A0,0x0000000000000011,0xFFFFC88F150D88A0,0x0000000000000002)
I guess it's because of how I allocate the memory? it crashes even if I don't try to disable interrupts and even if I do.

microsoft says there is "POOL_FLAG_NON_PAGED_EXECUTE Make allocation in the non-paged executable pool" First just try to put a ret in there to rule out any other issues.

You can rest assured that __readcr0 and __writecr0 do their work correctly. You don't need to disable the interrupts to clear CR0.WP. You can also probably link an objectfile assembled from an assembly source with your driver, instead of writing a shellcode. CR0.WP can only be cleared if CR4.CET is zero. Windows may reset CR0.WP on context switch, just like it needs to for CR4.CET. You may also be clearing CR0.WP on a single random (hardware) thread instead of all.

Hi @Jester I noticed that later and I did. The issue did not change, I still got the 'Uknown exception "mov cr0, rax"' meaning I can't move rax back to cr0.

Actually, CET is enabled per thread-basis using IA32_U_CET, so CR4.CET could be set (once at boot) even if no thread is using CET. If CR4.CET=1, you cannot set CR0.WP to zero.

@MargaretBloom Hello, thank you I will try right away. Is the CR4.CET bit 15?

@MargaretBloom Hey, I just wanted to ask
I used __writecr0 __writecr4... etc
but when I tried to do this manually by allocating memory and putting it there it failed, any idea why?
